# Passing merchant key and salt in website

Tags: django, security, paypal, payumoney, payu

I have integrated payu in my website for transaction. I have a doubt, in their dev guide they pass merchant key, salt, hash etc. to form parameters. Now, if anybody does an inspect element in my website then he/she can see those parameters.I want to know the best way people use payu apis and how do they make sure that mechant id, salt remains on server only. My backend is in django and front end in angular js

Answer (score 4):

Afaik, that hash is calculated in the backend based on a secret word known only by PayU and the merchant (you should keep that stored in the environment), therefore no security issues if someone inspects the form and see's those elements, paypal, cybersource, etc are also doing the same. No need to doubt, go ahead and finalise the integration.

To be able to use their API and integrate server2server method your employer should be PCI Compliance, which is not actually a small thing.

Answer (score -1):

I've not used Payu, but sensitive information like this should be stored in the Django settings files (which can only be read if you have access to the server) and only accessed by Django (rather than put in JS files which can be read by anyone).

The normal way to implement something like this would be to have the form POST to a Django View which retrieves the sensitive information from the settings files and then calls the API.